# Retrieve ONLY dowloaded songs from internal storage to make MP3 player in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

This is my code. As you can see I retrieve the songs from the internal storage      but in the MP3 player shows all the other "default" music the device has.
    Any help is appreciated.

```
public void getSongList() {

    ContentResolver musicResolver = getContentResolver();


    Uri musicUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

    Cursor musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri, null, null, null, null);

    if (musicCursor!=null && musicCursor.moveToFirst()){
        //get columns
        int titleColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
        int idColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
        int artistColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
        //add songs to list

        do {
            long thisId = musicCursor.getLong(idColumn);
            String thisTitle = musicCursor.getString(titleColumn);
            String thisArtist = musicCursor.getString(artistColumn);
            songList.add(new Song(thisId, thisTitle, thisArtist));
        }
        while (musicCursor.moveToNext());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [javadoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Audio.Media.html) for that constant says:

> The content:// style URI for the internal storage.

So, basically you lookup **all internally stored** content.

What makes you think that would be limited to downloaded content?

In other words: I think your whole idea will simply not work this way; you simply ask "give me all media that is currently located in the internal storage".

Answer (score 0):

Store downloaded songs in their own directory, and only load from that specific directory?